# OctoPrint webpage freezes (Setup on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian)

Tags: prusa-i3, octoprint, raspberry-pi

I have been using a software called ***OctoPrint*** that allows you to control your printer in your Browser. For sake of simplicity I have used ***Octopi***, a preinstalled image with OctoPrint, but now I would like to make some changes, and I decided to build OctroPrint by myself, the instructions for building it are here: https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint/wiki/Setup-on-a-Raspberry-Pi-running-Raspbian. The problem is that when I follow the first commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
cd ~
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev python-setuptools python-virtualenv git libyaml-dev build-essential
git clone https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint.git
cd OctoPrint
virtualenv venv
./venv/bin/pip install pip --upgrade
./venv/bin/python setup.py install
mkdir ~/.octoprint
sudo usermod -a -G tty pi
sudo usermod -a -G dialout pi
```

And then I start the octoprint server

```
 ~/OctoPrint/venv/bin/octoprint
```

The webpage of Octoprint freezes

[image]

I don't know if this is fixed in later commands, but I would like to get a sense of how all fits together before continue. It doesn't look that is the browser (I am capable to visit other websites without any problems), so is maybe Octoprint? How can I fix this? Did anyone have this problem before? Thanks in advance

---

The output in the console is:

```
2016-07-11 03:09:19,442 - octoprint.server - INFO - Starting OctoPrint 1.2.13 (master branch)
2016-07-11 03:09:19,502 - octoprint.plugin.core - INFO - Loading plugins from /home/pi/.octoprint/plugins, /home/pi/OctoPrint/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.2.13-py2.7.egg/octoprint/plugins and installed plugin packages...
2016-07-11 03:09:20,522 - octoprint.plugins.discovery - INFO - pybonjour is not installed, Zeroconf Discovery won't be available
2016-07-11 03:09:20,524 - octoprint.plugin.core - INFO - Found 6 plugin(s) providing 6 mixin implementations, 3 hook handlers
2016-07-11 03:09:20,533 - octoprint.filemanager.storage - INFO - Initializing the file metadata for /home/pi/.octoprint/uploads...
2016-07-11 03:09:20,536 - octoprint.filemanager.storage - INFO - ... file metadata for /home/pi/.octoprint/uploads initialized successfully.
2016-07-11 03:09:23,615 - octoprint.util.pip - INFO - Found pip at /home/pi/OctoPrint/venv/bin/pip, version is 8.1.2
2016-07-11 03:09:23,620 - octoprint.plugin.core - INFO - Initialized 6 plugin implementation(s)
2016-07-11 03:09:23,625 - octoprint.plugin.core - INFO - 6 plugin(s) registered with the system:
|  Announcement Plugin (bundled) = /home/pi/OctoPrint/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.2.13-py2.7.egg/octoprint/plugins/announcements
|  CuraEngine (<= 15.04) (bundled) = /home/pi/OctoPrint/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.2.13-py2.7.egg/octoprint/plugins/cura
|  Discovery (bundled) = /home/pi/OctoPrint/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.2.13-py2.7.egg/octoprint/plugins/discovery
|  Plugin Manager (bundled) = /home/pi/OctoPrint/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.2.13-py2.7.egg/octoprint/plugins/pluginmanager
|  Software Update (bundled) = /home/pi/OctoPrint/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.2.13-py2.7.egg/octoprint/plugins/softwareupdate
|  Virtual Printer (bundled) = /home/pi/OctoPrint/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OctoPrint-1.2.13-py2.7.egg/octoprint/plugins/virtual_printer
2016-07-11 03:09:23,628 - octoprint.filemanager - INFO - Adding backlog items from all storage types to analysis queue...
2016-07-11 03:09:23,639 - octoprint.filemanager - INFO - Added 0 items from storage type "local" to analysis queue
2016-07-11 03:09:23,644 - octoprint.server - INFO - Reset webasset folder /home/pi/.octoprint/generated/webassets...
2016-07-11 03:09:23,660 - octoprint.server - INFO - Reset webasset folder /home/pi/.octoprint/generated/.webassets-cache...
2016-07-11 03:09:24,082 - octoprint.plugins.discovery - INFO - Registered OctoPrint instance on raspberrypi for SSDP
2016-07-11 03:09:24,095 - octoprint.plugins.pluginmanager - INFO - Loaded plugin repository data from disk, was still valid
2016-07-11 03:09:24,135 - octoprint.server - INFO - Listening on http://0.0.0.0:5000
2016-07-11 03:09:24,602 - octoprint.plugins.announcements - INFO - Loaded channel _important from http://octoprint.org/feeds/important.xml in 0.43s
2016-07-11 03:09:25,271 - octoprint.server - INFO - Preemptively caching / for {'query_string': 'en', 'path': '/', 'base_url': 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/'}
2016-07-11 03:09:59,143 - octoprint.server.util.sockjs - INFO - New connection from client: 127.0.0.1
2016-07-11 03:09:59,884 - octoprint.plugins.cura - INFO - Path to CuraEngine has not been configured yet or does not exist (currently set to None), Cura will not be selectable for slicing
```

Comment: Do any errors pop up in the console? Press F12 and go to a console tab/menu, paste any errors you see. There might be an issue connecting to a machine. Do you have the machine turned on?

Comment: I just added the output in the console. The raspberry pi is turned on. Also I forgot to say that the website is fine when is loading, but after 3 or 4 seconds, it freezes

Comment: 1. You mentioned you started with the stock OctoPI build/installation but didn't mention that everything works without your changes.
2. Have you tried making your improvements one at a time to find out where the freezing web-page is introduced?

Comment: I am not making any improvements yet. I am just following the steps of https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint/wiki/Setup-on-a-Raspberry-Pi-running-Raspbian, and I am stuck in that step

Answer (score 1):

Is it the Raspberry Pi that locks up, or just the webpage? If the whole thing becomes unresponsive I would consider reviewing your overclocking settings. If you've set one of the higher overclocking values in the config script, this can often lead to random lockups.  If you don't see the config script every time you boot the Pi, you can access it by typing the following into a terminal window.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

You can find out how to change the overclocking settings from the config script in [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md)